# Scrapy, issue with response.follow

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

```
def parse(self, response):

    countries = response.xpath('//div[@class="state-names-list-us"]/ul/a')

    for country in countries:
        link = country.xpath(".//@href").get()
        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_frame)

def parse_frame(self, response):
    holder = response.xpath('//div[@class ="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget '
                            'hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text"]/iframe')
    for hold in holder:
        test = hold.xpath('.//@src').get()
        yield response.follow(url=test)
```

parse method gets the link to a page and then that link is used by parse_frame to get another link which has info to be scraped.

The parse_frame gets the link for the first iteration but then does not do it for the rest. How should I fix this issue as I wish to get the link for all the iterations. If you take a look at the output it does get the link only for the first one.

{2022-07-21 14:18:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.insulators.org/union-directory/mississippi>](https://www.insulators.org/union-directory/mississippi%3E) (referer: https://www.insulators.org/union-directory)
2022-07-21 14:18:33 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.hfiunionhall.org': <GET [https://www.hfiunionhall.org/pages/localDetails.asp?where=DE&searchType=State>](https://www.hfiunionhall.org/pages/localDetails.asp?where=DE&searchType=State%3E)
}

[image]

Comment: What is your end goal? What are you trying to scrape (complete url, what info), and in what format?

Comment: 1) http://www.insulators.org/union-directory/ 2) https://www.insulators.org/union-directory/alabama 3) https://www.hfiunionhall.org/pages/localDetails.asp?where=MD&searchType=State So, the first link has a list of states and the second link has an iframe tag which gets me to the 3rd link where the data can be accessed using :- response.xpath('(//tr)[7]/td/span/text()').getall() I am trying to make this happen for all 50 states